# Is this a MATLAB bug? Is this a common problem?

Tags: matlab

My MATLAB version is R2012a.

Why is 1.1-0.2 not equal to 0.9 in MATLAB?

This is awful!

> >>1.1-0.2 == 0.9
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>  0
> ```

Comment: This is due to [floating point accuracy](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html). Not all numbers can be represented exactly by FP numbers. You should never rely on comparisons like the one above. [Somewhat related.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422510/why-does-0-06-0-01-0-07-in-coldfusion)

Comment: The general canonical (84 answers. Nearly 4000 upvotes): *[Is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)*?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is not a MATLAB issue; it is a floating point issue. You'll get the same result in C++ (or any programming language that conforms to [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) for that matter):

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int, char **) {
    std::cout << (1.1-0.2==0.9) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0
```

This is because 1.1 and 0.9 [cannot be represented exactly in binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system#Fractions_in_binary). It's like expressing 1/3 in decimal: you'll have to write

```
0.33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333...
```

and continue indefinitely. But no matter how long you continue, you'll never get it right.

In floating point, you only have so many digits you can store, so the calculation will have to stop somewhere. The result of the calculation is actually

```
>> 1.1-0.2
ans =
     9.000000000000001e-01
```

which is pretty close, but not quite correct.

Because of this, you should always think twice before using `==` to compare two floating-point numbers; it is rare that the `==` operator can be applied without some "strange" consequences like the one you just encountered.

It is better to use a round-off specific tolerance, like

```
abs(1.1-0.2 - 0.9) <= eps(0.9)
```

where `eps` is a MATLAB function which returns the [spacing-between-doubles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) for a specific double value. But really, this is not a catch-all-end-all solution; correctly comparing floating points is a tricky business.

Comment: @carlosfigueira: well, "never" is just too much of a blanket statement...there are plenty of cases where plain test-for-equality of two floats is justified.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I'd argue otherwise - even zero has two representations! Ok, let me rephrase then: in the vast majority of scenarios, you shouldn't compare floating point numbers for equality; what you should do instead is to use some "accepted error" instead.

Comment: For this "accepted error" you have matlab's `eps` for single precision `eps('single')` and `eps('double')` for double precision. You can use the appropriate `eps` to determine if two float numbers are close enough.

Comment: @Shai: The spacing between doubles varies greatly from number to number. The proper way to go would be to use `eps(0.9)` for the comparison. Perhaps this is what you meant, but oh well.

Comment: @Shai: fun fact I learned the other day: **half** of all the representable values in IEEE754 double-precision lie in the interval (-1 1)

Comment: I did not find an example where this fails, but I suspect that if you have more complicated calculations you may want to use something like `10*eps` to be safe.

Comment: Really depends on the calculations preceding the comparison. e.g. a= (1e13+1)/3-(1e13)/3; abs(a - 1/3) < eps(1/3)

Comment: @grantnz: indeed. Comparison between floats is a tricky business...`eps ` is really *not* a catch-all for all comparisons. A catch-all does not even *exist*, unless you sacrifice an exorbitantly large amount of performance.

Answer (score 3):

http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_0.3-0.2-0.1_not_equal_to_zero_.28or_similar.29.3F

Scroll to "Why is 0.3 - 0.2 - 0.1 (or similar) not equal to zero?"

"Some floating point numbers can not be represented exactly in binary form....If you're trying to compare two floating-point numbers, be very careful about using == to do so. An alternate comparison method is to check if the two numbers you're comparing are "close enough""

Answer (score 2):

A good function to use for these sorts of things to see what is going on is `num2strexact` from file exchange

```
num2strexact(1.1-0.2)
0.9000000000000001332267629550187848508358001708984375


num2strexact(0.9)
0.90000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
```

You see, they are not the same.

Look at the different when using double vs. syms

```
num2strexact((1.1-0.2)-0.9)
1.1102230246251565404236316680908203125e-16


sym('(1.1-0.2)-0.9') 
1.8367099231598242312011508394098e-40
```