# How to compare two double values in matlab?

Tags: matlab, double

I want to compare two double values. I know the value of `MinimumValue`, which is `3.5261e+04`. This `MinimumValue` I got from an array `e`. My code has to print first statement `'recognized face'` because both value are same. But my code is displaying second statement `'unrecognized face'`.

What is the mistake in my code?

```
MinimumValue = min(e)

theta = 3.5261e+04;

if (MinimumValue <= theta)
    fprintf('recognized face\n');
else
    fprintf('unrecognized face\n');
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699596/is-this-a-matlab-bug-do-you-have-the-same-issue/13699708#13699708

Comment: @patrik: it's not a duplicate, because the OP's not checking for *equality*. It's (probably) a display issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches:

1. Replace `if MinimumValue<=theta` with `if MinimumValue == theta`. This is the easier but probably poorer approach for your problem.
2. Chances are, `MinimumValue` is different from `theta` by a very small amount. If you are doing some calculations by hand to determine that `theta = 3.5261e+04`, and believe there are more decimal places, you should use `format long` to determine the actual value of `theta` to 15 significant figures. After that, you can use `if abs(MinimumValue - theta) <= eps` (edit: As patrick has noted in the comment below, you should compare to some user-defined tolerance or `eps` instead of `realmin('double'`).

Comment: I have to check for both condition "less than or equal to".

Comment: @user3456881: indeed, print the value of `MinimumValue` with `format long e` turned on; you'll probably see then why the test fails.

Comment: A warning here, I would not recommend comparing to realmin. which is of magnitude `10^-311`. No floating points operations can be of that accuracy. The minimum floating point precision is somewhere of 10^-16. Then the machine error will be significant. This is why a machine epsilon (`eps`) in matlab, which is the maximal precision of floating point operations. This is set to 2^-52. So rather try `if abs(MinimumValue - theta) <= eps`, or better set a tolerance `tol` define by you

Comment: @patrik: Good catch there, I've edited my response to credit your comment.