# outer product of matrix rows (e.g. A(i,:)^T * A(i,:) for all rows i) + mean of same element in all submatrices created

Tags: matlab, matrix, rows, product, outer-join

I'm trying to calculate the outer product of all rows in a matrix. So far I'm doing the following:

```
A = rand(10,8);
[N J] = size(A);
for i = 1:N,
    B(((i-1)*J+1):J+((i-1)*J),:) = A(i,:)'*A(i,:)
end
```

I then take the mean of the same elements of the same row in each submatrix created above.

```
for j=1:J,
    C(1:J,j) = accumarray(repmat((1:J)',N,1),B(:,j)).*(1/N); 
end
```

Now this works, but my input matrix will eventually be a number of magnitudes larger, so a vectorized version would be nice. I assume there is some way to do this with permute and bsxfun but the solutions for outer product I have seen so far don't seem to apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can compute `C` directly as

```
C = mean(bsxfun(@times, permute(A, [2 3 1]), permute(A, [3 2 1])), 3);
```

Or, if you really need the `B` variable, you can do it this way:

```
B_3D = bsxfun(@times, A.', permute(A,[3 1 2])); %'// 3D array
B = reshape(B_3D, numel(A), []);
C = mean(permute(B_3D, [1 3 2]), 3);
```

Comment: This answer is great and results look to be equal. But if I try to verify with iseqaul() then it returns 0. Why could this be the case?

Comment: @TiredHornet Most probably floating point precision issues. How about manually inspect some of the values?

Comment: You should always [__beware of comparing reals__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699596/is-this-a-matlab-bug-do-you-have-the-same-issue), for the reason Divakar has said. Instead, try `yourC ./ myC` and check it gives all entries equal to `1` except for finite precission issues

Comment: @Luis Mendo: Very nice idea. I did that and it I get all ones.

Comment: @TiredHornet Note they are not actually ones, but very close (try for example `yourC./myC-1`). That's normal; it happens because of finite numerical precision

Comment: @Luis Mendo Okay, I'll remember that. Now, it is time to learn how to use permute on my own. Hard to get your head this flipping of dimensions...

Comment: @TiredHornet Yes, it's hard initially, but you kind-of get used :-) The basic idea is to make dimensions non-coincident if you want `bsxfun` to compute all "combinations" involving those dimensions