# Why fix((20.45-20)*60) is not equal with fix((20)*60) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, floating-point, precision, computation

There is an interesting question on Facebook which I encountered. He asks that he is using MATLAB R2014a (64-bit version) and ran this code:-

```
x = 0.45;
min = fix((x)*60);
fprintf('min = %d \n', min);

x = 20.45
min = fix((x-20)*60);
fprintf('min = %d \n', min);
```

The results are following:

```
>> tx
min = 27
min = 26
```

which are incorrect because (20.45 - 20) should give the same result as 0.45, but it does not.

He also attempted %f but it still gave the same result.

At first, I thought it was problem with storing floating point but after I calculated it, it did not seem to be the right answer.

So, I think this question is interesting and challenging. Could anyone please help me explain how this happens?

[image: Where the answers are not equal.]

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is an error from storing floating point . `0.45` is not `20.45-20`

Comment: Useful lecture: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: The closest double to 0.45 is 0.450000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125, slightly larger than exact. The closest double to 20.45 is 20.449999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875, slightly smaller than exact. 20.45-20 evaluates to 0.449999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875

Comment: Bsically, someone designed that code to confuse you ;)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Great! May I know how you calculated that? I need to try with other numbers. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Thammarith I used Java's exact conversion of double to BigDecimal, and exact BigDecimal toString. There are also web sites such as [Decimal to Floating-Point Converter](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/). Many languages, by default, display a shorter approximation rather than the exact value of a float or double.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are seeing is to do with storing floating point numbers, see:

```
20.45-20==0.45
```

When you do the calculation in your head it comes out the same, but in the computer it doesn't see [this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699596/is-this-a-matlab-bug-do-you-have-the-same-issue)